# Application starts without text [all text is in blocks]

Tags: 18.04, fonts, snap

I have noticed that when I install some applications via snap, the applications themselves, the text, is in blocks and not, as it should be, in text form. It seems as if the font is not loaded. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here I've noticed it with poedit2, but it appears that it happens with others to (Insomnia, ...)

Here is a picture of what it looks like.
[image: poedit without text]